# Scope of variables using csv reader in Python

Tags: python, csv, variables, scope, reference

When I run this function on the file with 10 lines, it prints out the lines, but returns the length of 0. If I reverse the order, it prints out the length, but not the file content. I suppose this is a scope related issue, but not sure how to fix it

```
def read_samples(name):
    with open ( '../data/samples/' + name + '.csv', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as file:
        data = csv.reader(file)
        for row in data:
            print (row)
        lines = len ( list ( data ) )
        print(lines)
```

Comment: It's not scope-related; there is only one scope involved here, the local scope of the function. Neither `with` nor `for` create a new scope.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting 0 because you have already looped over data.So now it is `0`.It is an iterator which is consumed.

```
def read_samples(name):
    with open ( '../data/samples/' + name + '.csv', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as file:
        data = csv.reader(file)
        x=0
        for row in data:
            x+=1
            print (row)
        lines = x
        print(lines)
```

Comment: Or simpler, `for lines, row in enumerate(data, start=1):` When the loop completes, `lines` will contain the number of rows yielded by the iterator, i.e., the length.

Answer (score 1):

The file reader remembers its place in the file like a bookmark

Printing each line and getting the length both move the bookmark all the way to the end of the file

Add `data.seek(0)` between the loop and getting the length. This moves the bookmark back to the start of the file

Answer (score 0):

The `csv.reader()` function returns an iterator (which are "consumed" when you use them) so you can only use `data` once. You can <s>coerce</s> convert it to a list before you do any operations on it to do what you want, e.g. `data = list(data)`.

Comment: It's not a coercion; you are creating a new `list` object using the elements of the iterator, not telling Python to treat the `reader` object as a list.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
def read_samples(name):
    with open ( '../data/samples/' + name + '.csv', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as file:
        my_list = []
        data = csv.reader(file)
        for row in data:
            print (row)
            my_list.append(row)
        lines = len (my_list)
        print(lines)
```